# filter out hdfs audit logs for non-directory inodes

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, logstash, audit-logging

I am populating HDFS audit log messages into a Kafka topic using logstash.

a sample message which I receive in Kafka topic has this format:

```
allowed=true    ugi={myuser} (auth:SIMPLE)  ip={/x.x.x.x}   cmd={listStatus, open, ...} src={src path} dst={destination path} perm=null proto=rpc
```

Is there a way to filter out all those messages which their "src" attribute points to a non-directory indoe on filesystem? I am only interested to get messages for directories on HDFS!

Comment: Have you tried any Logstash configuration options yet?

Comment: what configuration do you mean specifically?